# Cannot move Google geocoded data to Django form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, google-maps

I am using Django and Google maps API to geocode an address and return the results to a form which would in turn be sent to another view.

When I add the address to the form input (form.user_entered_address) and click submit, I get the correct response from this alert:

```
alert("latitude:" + result.lat());
```

But I just cannot seem to get the data to stick to the form.  I tried the following to see if the data gets attached to the form:

```
alert($('#longitude').val());
alert($('#id_longitude').val());
```

but they both say undefined.  Also, the action of the form does not work (i.e. it does not redirect to the 'testingx' view with the form data, it just stays on the index.html page.

I have been trying to debug this for a week steady and an out of ideas.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks,

Ivan

INDEX.html

```
<html>

<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Testing out ATM form</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

$('#search_form').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var onSuccess = function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            result = results[0].geometry.location;
            $('this').prepend('<input type = "hidden" id="latitude" value"' + result.lat() + '">');
            $('this').prepend('<input type = "hidden" id="longitude" value"' + result.lng() + '">');
            $('this').prepend('<input type = "hidden" id="formatted_address" value"' + result.formatted_address + '">');

            alert("latitude:" + result.lat());

            alert($('#longitude').val());


        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason' + status);
        }
        $('this').trigger('submit');
    }
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': search_form.user_entered_address.value
                    }, onSuccess);
    });
});


</script>
```

```
<form action="{% url 'testingx' %}" id="search_form"  method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.user_entered_address }}

    <input type="submit" id="submit">

</form>



</body>
</html>
```

FORMS.py

from django import forms

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    user_entered_address = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=255)
    full_address = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    latitude = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    longitude = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo in your Javascript code. You are missing the = sign next to value in your prepend calls.

Also, your elements will need a name attribute that matches the django form field name in order for this to work. Something like

```
$('this').prepend('<input type = "hidden" id="latitude" name="latitude" value="' + result.lat() + '">');
$('this').prepend('<input type = "hidden" id="longitude" name="longitude" value="' + result.lng() + '">');
$('this').prepend('<input type = "hidden" id="formatted_address" name="formatted_address" value="' + result.formatted_address + '">');
```

An easier (and maybe cleaner way) might be to output the hidden fields in your django form, then just setting the value on the existing fields.

In your template you can add

```
 {{ form.latitude }}
 {{ form.longitude }}
 {{ form.formatted_address }}
```

And then in Javascript you should be able to do `$('#id_latitude').val(result.lat());`

Comment: Hi Pierre,  Thank you for the response.  I'll give this a try and report back the results and any final outcomes.

Comment: Hi again,  both of your suggestions worked perfectly.  One issue I am having is the final step in getting the form to submit.  e.preventDefault() is doing what it should (stopping the submit functionality so that the geocoding can complete).  However, the $(this).trigger("submit"); does not do anything.  I can delete it, or include it and nothing changes.  WhenI change it to $('#search_form').trigger("submit"), it becomes an infinite loop.  I am not sure how to get the form to send the data to the other view at this point. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Should probably be a different question ... but in your original question you use $('this'). That would also be a typo. It should be $(this) without the single quotes.

Comment: Thanks Pierre.  Those quotes were me trying anything to get the trigger to work.  I'll post as a new Q after doing some more searching on the issue at hand.